# Use static image for launch image iOS 9 from Asset Catalog

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard, launch

I'm trying to use a static image on my `LaunchScreen.storyboard`, so we need unique sizes for each device.

In my assets folder I can great a launch image `Image Set` that allows me to add images for each device, however I just get a blank launch image when I use these in an `Image View`. A regular image doesn't give enough options (only 1x, 2x, 3x for iPhone/iPad). What's the best way to do this?

To clarify: how can I use a full screen static image that fits on say both a 4S and iPhone 5 when both those images are technically 2x? Creating a new launch images asset gives all these options for different screen sizes, however it can't be used in storyboard as an image like a regular asset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using the `LaunchImage` set, add a normal image set of the image that you want to be on the launch screen to your .xcassets file. Next, add a UIImageView to the UIViewController in your `LaunchScreen.storyboard` and set the image using the Attribute Inspector.

**Step 1: Add your image assets to the .xcassets file**

[image: Add assets to the .xcassets file]

**Step 2: Add a UIImageView to the LaunchScreen.storyboard file**

[image: Add a UIImageView to the LaunchScreen.storyboard file]

**Step 3: Add constraints to the UIImageView and set the image in the Attribute Inspector**

**BTW**, don't forget to make sure that the `Launch Screen File` in your .xcodeproj is set to your LaunchScreen starboard file!

[image: Make sure the file is correct in your .xcodeproj file!]

You should now be good to go!

#### UPDATE: Static Launch Image using only the .xcassets file

If you want to use a full screen static image on launch, you can use just a LaunchImage set in your .xcassets file.

If you don't already have a .xcassets file in your project, add a new file like so: File > New > File > iOS Resource > Asset Catalog.

[image: Add Launch Image set to .xcassets file]

Next, open your .xcassets file and right click > App Icons & Launch Images > New iOS Launch Image

[image: Add specific Launch Screen Images]

Now you can add specific launch images for iPhone 4(S), 5(S/C), 6(S) and 6(S) Plus. (BTW, I've selected only the portrait orientation for this image set).

[image: Leave Launch Screen Field in blank]

The last, and very important step, is to leave the **Launch Screen File** field in blank in your target settings!

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer but this isn't actually the issue I'm having. I want to use a static image yes, but Assets only have 1x, 2x and 3x options. My question is, how can I use a full screen static image that fits on say both a 4S and iPhone 5 when both those images are technically 2x? Creating a new launch images asset gives all these options for different screen sizes, however it can't be used in storyboard as an image like a regular asset.

Comment: @ChrisByatt I've updated my answer to better fit your need. This second method will let you upload different launch images for the different screen sizes. Specifically, you can now add separate launch images for the iPhone 4(S), iPhone 5(S/C), iPhone 6(S) and iPhone 6(S) Plus. I've also added the sizes you need for the different screens. I hope this helps!

Comment: Aaaah you leave it blank. That's where I went wrong!!

Comment: @ChrisByatt Don't forget to mark my answer as correct! I'm glad to have helped. :D